# Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}} = 0 $

Tags: limits

Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}} = 0   $

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. I want to find $N$ such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ guarantees $ \left | \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}} - 0  \right | < \epsilon$.

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}} < \epsilon$ 
$\Leftarrow \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{4}{3} < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow n > \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{\epsilon} \Rightarrow n \geq N$

Take $N = \left \lfloor \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right \rfloor + 1$

In the above proof, I'm confused as to how $\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}} < \epsilon$ 
$\Leftarrow \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{4}{3} < \epsilon$. How did $\frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}}$ become $\frac{4}{3} $?

Comment: I suppose that, in the title, $x$ stands fot $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $n \in \mathbb N \implies n \geq 1$, we know that:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \leq 1 \iff 3 + \frac{1}{n} \leq 4
$$
as well as that:
$$
\frac{-1}{n} \geq -1 \iff 4 - \frac{1}{n} \geq 3
$$

Now to make a fraction smaller, we can either decrease the numerator or increase the denominator. Thus, it follows that:
$$
\epsilon > \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{4}{3}
\geq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\frac{3 + \frac{1}{n}}{4 - \frac{1}{n}}$ decreases when $n$ increases to infinity.

Comment: I guess what's the significance of using $\frac{4}{3}$? is it just to simplify the expression

Comment: @Adrian Probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for all $n \geq 1$, $3 + \dfrac{1}{n} \leq 4$, and $4 - \dfrac{1}{n} \geq 3$. Thus: $\dfrac{3+\dfrac{1}{n}}{4 - \dfrac{1}{n}} \leq \dfrac{4}{3}$. Thus given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N_{0} =\lfloor\dfrac{4}{3\epsilon}\rfloor + 1$, then if $n > N_0$, we have: $\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot \dfrac{3+\dfrac{1}{n}}{4 - \dfrac{1}{n}} < \dfrac{4}{3n} < \epsilon$, and the conclusion follows.